# Reference counter for intrusive smart pointers

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

The following is a code excerpt written by a colleague that is no longer working with us. I have questions as to why this code was written in this way and not any other. My impression of the colleague is a very good one, he was one of the few people capable of compiling C++ code in his head.

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>

namespace boost
{

/*****************************************
class RefCounter
{
protected:
    RefCounter() : m_refCount(0) {}
    virtual ~RefCounter() { }

private:
    friend void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounter * p);
    friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(RefCounter * p);

    volatile long m_refCount;

    virtual void incRef() {__sync_add_and_fetch(&m_refCount, 1);}
    virtual void decRef() {if (__sync_sub_and_fetch(&m_refCount, 1) == 0) delete this;}
};

inline void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(RefCounter * p)
{
    p->incRef();
}

inline void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounter * p)
{
    p->decRef();
}
************************************************/

class RefCounter
{
protected:
    RefCounter() : m_refCount(0) {}
    RefCounter(const RefCounter&) : m_refCount(0) {}
    virtual ~RefCounter() {}

    long getRefCount() const {return m_refCount;}

private:
    friend void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounter * p);
    friend void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(RefCounter * p);
    volatile long m_refCount;
};

inline void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(RefCounter * p)
{
    __sync_add_and_fetch(&p->m_refCount, 1);
}

inline void intrusive_ptr_release(RefCounter * p)
{
    if (__sync_sub_and_fetch(&p->m_refCount, 1) == 0) delete p;
}

} // namespace boost
```

Example of use:

```
struct Foo : public boost::RefCounter
{
    int a;
};

typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<Foo> FooIntrusivePtr;
FooIntrusivePtr fooPtr;
```

My questions are the following:

1. Why use `friend` keywords? Why not declare the functions public?
2. Why use `volative` keyword? Where and why could the compiler aggressively optimize this value? Or was this keyword merely used as a precaution?

And as a bonus, why was the previous approach (commented out) replaced with the existing code? Was something wrong with the previous approach, a bug or special scenario which did not work as intended?

Much appreciated.

Comment: 1. Those functions are free floating. They aren't members of the class. They are tagged as friends so that they and only they can operate on the private data of RefCounter.

Comment: 2. It is unportable compiler specific atomic variable.

Comment: Others have stated **what the code is doing** and **why it works that way** (e.g., the free functions and why their implementation requires the `friend` keyword). However, I don't think anyone, except the author of the code, can explain the rationale for doing it that way versus an alternative method (e.g., private member functions).

Comment: @JamesAdkison The free functions are required by the `boost::intrusive_ptr<>`. Why he switched from using private methods and instead adjusting the `m_refCount` directly is harder to explain. I suspect he decided the `virtual` functions were not needed and since he had to make the free functions friends anyway (to prevent public access to the refcount), he could just change the variable directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions are marked `friend` so that they can edit the `m_refCount` member variable of the class even though it's private and the functions are not part of the class itself.

The `volatile` keyword as well as why it's using the `__sync_` functions is to allow this implementation to work in a multi-threaded environment without using a mutex.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot You're right I missed that. I removed the part about the old version.